# How do I obtain specific styles from a CSS style sheet using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I've tried *element.style.getPropertyValue* but that only obtains the text within the `style` attribute of the element. How would I get properties and values from the style element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the full style for the element, including styles it's been assigned by style sheets, via the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) function on most browsers, or via the [`currentStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on IE. (Note that one of those is a function, the other is a property.)

---

There are a number of browser idiosyncrasies around computed styles. This is one of the things I'd use a good library for, something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). That way you're leveraging the work (and most importantly, workarounds) other people have already done. Just to give one example: Some versions of WebKit (the renderer used by Chrome and Safari) mis-report the `margin-right` property in some situations. jQuery tests to see if that's the case and, if so, works around it for you. I don't know how many of the others work around that *specific* issue, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
function getStyle(element, styleProperty) {
    if (element.currentStyle)
        return element.currentStyle[styleProperty];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(styleProperty);
    return value;
}
```